# Rate/Flow analysis using integration

Tags: integration, functions

I'm given a problem that a pump is removing oil at a rate modeled by the function $R(t)=2+cos(\pi t/11)$ over the interval t=[0,6]. And I'm supposed to find the volume of oil removed in the 6 hour period defined by the interval. So, naturally I took the integral and solved for area, which gave me 15.4657, and the system wants the answer to 3 decimal places, I put in 15.465 because the system is finicky, did I solve the problem wrong, or is it a general rounding error?

Comment: To 3 decimal places 15.4657 is 15.466

Comment: alright, Thank you for double checking for me, just needed a second set of eyes